# how to configure a asyncAcks spring kafka listener?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I using spring kafka to consumer messages from kafka. I want to use batch listener to consume a topic with asyncAcks mode. But I did not find how to configure it in the application.properties for it.

```
    @KafkaListener(groupId = "${app.kafka.shipment-historic-topic.group-id}",
            topics = "${app.kafka.shipment-historic-topic.topic-name}",
            autoStartup = "${app.kafka.shipment-historic-topic.enabled}",
            batch = "true",
            properties = {"spring.json.value.default.type=com.xxx.events.model.shipment.ShipmentEvent"}
    )
    public void dispatchEvent(@Payload List<ConsumerRecord<String, ShipmentEvent>> shipmentEventRecords
    ) {
 //consumer logic
}
```

With above code, I could receive list of consumer record. It works properly. In application.yaml. I have below configure. I could see the ack mode was used properly as configure here. But in KafkaMessageListenerContainer, I see the container properties is still with asyncAcks false.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    listener:
      ack-mode: BATCH
      async-acks: true
```

May u know in with a batch listener how could I configure in application.yaml the container use asyncAcks mode?

Answer (score 1):

Use a container customizer to set the container property - it is not available as a Boot listener property.

However, async acks make no sense for a batch listener (one that receives all the results from a poll in a `List`) since the batch is acknowledged as a whole and all records from a poll must be acked before the next batch is fetched.

Comment: @michaldo - that edit was incorrect

Comment: I agree - my fault